# Pivot Cache Type Mismatch error VB.NET Excel

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, pivot-table

Please see bottom edit for where I am currently at, thank you.

I have created a pivot table that works fine when the pivot cache is defined as:

```
        Dim ptCache As Excel.PivotCache = mainHighway.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, SourceData:=mainHighwayData.Range("a1:v7500"))
```

My problem is that the number of rows changes from day to day, so I figure out the number of rows in the worksheet and then use that in my pivot cache:

```
Dim highlRow As Integer
highlRow = mainHighwayData.Cells.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
Dim ptCache As Excel.PivotCache = mainHighway.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, SourceData:=mainHighwayData.Range("a1:V" & highlRow))
```

This solution has worked great for me historically, but when I do it here, I get:

```
Type mismatch. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))
```

I have been fiddling around with it a fair bit and found that if I do:

```
highlRow = 7000
Dim ptCache As Excel.PivotCache = mainHighway.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, SourceData:=mainHighwayData.Range("a1:V" & highlRow))
```

It works fine, so I am left wondering what is the problem with how I define highlRow using the specialcells command and store it as an integer. I feel like there is some kind of type or casting issue here, but I can't put my finger on it. I tried:

```
highlRow = CType(mainHighwayData.Cells.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row, Integer)
```

And that was no good either. Perhaps my method for finding the last row is just not applicable here? Anyway, I have spent a long time tinkering with it and I am just spinning my wheels at this point. If you have any thoughts it would be much appreciated.

Thank you as always SO.

edit: I also tried out:

```
UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

Which has worked historically and it was also not able to run. At this point I am very curious as to why pivot cache specifically seems to have this issue.

@charles had a good idea to try other ways of getting the last cell. I tried:

```
highlRow = mainHighwayData.Range("A65535").End(XlDirection.xlUp).Row
```

I got it to give the correct rows, but it still throws the type mismatch error.

```
highlRow = mainHighwayData.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, SearchDirection:=XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious).Row
```

This returns the proper number for the last row, but once again throws the same type mismatch error.

Edit: I found out another bit of information, but I am not sure what to do with it. The pivot table works fine if the values in it are <= 65536, but the second I increase the range to 65537 I get the type mismatch that has been haunting me. This is true for all numbers >= 65537. I know that 65535 or there abouts used to be the last row in excel, but that is no longer the case. Also when I create the pivot table manually in excel I have no trouble and it has all of the data. I am using int or long, so it should not be an overflow or anything. Anyone have any thoughts on why VB.NET will not let me make a pivot table based on data with more than 65537 rows?

Comment: What is the value of highlRow after you assign it using the SpecialCells code?

Comment: 17105 or something similar. It appears to just be a number to me, which is what is confusing me. I don't see how it is different from just setting it equal to 17105.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it was a bit of a nightmare, but I found a fix that works. I noticed that people in vba have the same trouble and they were switching to r1c1 notation, but I couldn't get that working either, but I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450450/type-mismatch-error-when-creating-a-pivot-table-in-excel-with-vba) and the last comment on the answer there had the solution.

```
highlRow = mainHighwayData.Range("A500000").End(XlDirection.xlUp).Row
Dim rng As Excel.Range
rng = mainHighwayData.Range("A1:Q" & highlRow)
mainHighway.Names.Add(Name:="Range1", RefersTo:=rng)
Dim ptCache As Excel.PivotCache = mainHighway.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, SourceData:="Range1")
```

So you create a named range and then refer to it. I guess the idea is you need to abstract away from simple range objects and that will allow you to make your pivot table.

Answer (score 1):

SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell) gives you the last cell that has been used. Used includes any kind of formatting, so the last cell may not contain any valid data and so could cause the pivotCache creation to fail.
 Try a more robust way of finding the last cell containing data
You could try LastRow = Range("A65535").end(xlup).row 
or LastRow = Cells.Find("*",SearchOrder:=xlByRows,SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Comment: That is a good idea. I tried both of your ideas and updated my post with the code and results.

Comment: Any thoughts on why the first approach keeps returning 1 (see edit in main post for code)?

Comment: I sorted it out. I needed to go further down in the worksheet than 65000. It still throws the same type mismatch error. A good idea though, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this problem on this way:

```
Excel.Worksheet oSheet = oBook.Worksheets.get_Item(sourceSheet);

Excel.Range oRange = oSheet.UsedRange;

oBook.Names.Add(Name: "Range1", RefersTo: oRange);

Excel.PivotCache oPivotCache = oBook.PivotCaches().Add(SourceType: Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, SourceData: "Range1");
```