# Excel VBA PivotCaches won't accept source

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, pivot-table

I created a sub that automatically creates a pivot table based on a source range. The code works fine when the source data is a small range. However, when I run it on some bigger data (110'000 rows) I get run time error 13 (Type Mismatch).

I don't understand why it does this. I can run the exact same code on another range, and all is well???

Does someone have a suggestion why this would happen?

```
Set rDataRange = wsData.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    ' Create the cache
Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
SourceData:=rDataRange)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question appears to be asking (and answering) a very similar question:  [Type mismatch error when creating a pivot table in Excel with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450450/type-mismatch-error-when-creating-a-pivot-table-in-excel-with-vba)

Are you absolutely sure your reference to the larger range is valid?  Are you positive the larger range is not missing a header, doesn't contain an extra blank row or column, doesn't have any bad data?

Comment: +1 most likely missing header. Try to add the pivot table manually (without macro) and see what issues you encounter. Current region shortcut is Ctrl+A or Ctrl+Shift+8

Comment: Checked it by looking at the selection using rDataRange.select and the headers are included. Will try the solution described in the other post... and come back.

Comment: Other Post contained the answer... well, at least it provided a workaround solution. The answer as to why this doesn't work still baffeles me... and will likely pop up to bite me in the butt at another point. Thanks ExactaBox and nutsch!